# evenly distribute the buttons of an html tabbed menu

Tags: html, css

The buttons are aligned to the left. I can't figure out how to make them be evenly distributed and be at the center so it can be responsive

[image]

```css
    .tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
 <button class="tablinks">Today</button>
 <button class="tablinks">This Week</button>
 <button class="tablinks">This Month</button>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` stack snippet and paste relevant HTML and CSS as a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way just add width:33% for the button

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tab button {
  width: 33.33%;;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
   <button class="tablinks">Today</button>
   <button class="tablinks">This Week</button>
   <button class="tablinks">This Month</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

display flex gives various options to get your request. For instance, space-evenly

```css
.tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
   <button class="tablinks">Today</button>
   <button class="tablinks">This Week</button>
   <button class="tablinks">This Month</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Way better than floats.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but you can also have your buttons use [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), here is a working snippet:

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  min-width: 33%;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks">Today</button>
  <button class="tablinks">This Week</button>
  <button class="tablinks">This Month</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where you can make tabs evenly.
(note: this is only HTML not working example.)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cdd17d;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #e0e39d;
}

div {
  background-color: #e0e39d;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='active'>asia</li>
  <li>australia</li>
  <li>new zealand</li>
</ul>
<div></div>
```